# Access MS Graph data across tenants and ext principals

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, multi-tenant

Let's say I have two or more O365 tenants and an external application using Azure client credentials that wants to read user data in these tenants.

Is it then possible to set access up so that the external application can obtain an OAuth access token for tenant 1, and use it to also read data in tenant 2, by some sort of tenant delegated access? For example let's say I have two users `foo@tenant1.com` and `bar@tenant2.com`, where `foo` belongs to tenant 1 and `bar` belongs to tenant 2, and I want to read e.g. e-mail or calendar events for these two users - is it then possible to authenticate *once* and read the data for both users using the same access token? Or is it absolutely necessary to group users by tenancy, i.e., find the matching tenant of each user, authenticate into that tenant and then read the data for the users within that tenant, separately?

What if the data itself spans multiple tenants, such as a user in tenant 1 creating a calendar event where users from tenant 2 are attendees, and perhaps using a resource such as a meeting room from tenant 3. How does O365 handle this? I've seen sometimes that principals from one tenant are being allowed into another tenant and given a special "guest" or "external" principal such as `foo@tenant1.com` being let into tenant 2 as `foo_tenant1.com#EXT#@tenant2.com`. Does this happen automatically? What if this external principal was used in the scenario above - could I obtain an access token for tenant2 and then fetch user data for the `foo_tenant1.com#EXT#@tenant2.com` principal even though it actually resides in tenant1?

If possible, what needs to be set up in Azure/AD to allow for this delegation of access between tenants?

Comment: It really depends if you have configured federation across the tenants and their domains what level of access is given to the IDs that are accessing them.

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT Thanks for your response. Ok, so it sounds like it's at least possible to set up this kind of federation. Would you know of a good documentation resource for setting that up? Also, I'm curious on how external tenant principals are addressed in such a setup, whether that `#EXT#` scheme must be used when fetching data for a principal belonging to another tenant, or if MS Graph sorts that out "under the hood" for you?

Comment: Once you federate a tenant through Azure AD B2B, the guest user from other tenant accessing your resources needs to have permissions to access Microsoft Graph API and then accordingly, it can retrieve information.

Answer (score 1):

•   As per what you have described in your question, I have understood that you must access other tenant’s users’ data through your tenant’s ID. Also, you want that your tenant’s ID can be used to access user data from multiple tenants. Thus, in your scenario, you can use federation between the various external domains to allow your tenant’s ID to access user data and applications from another tenant. Azure AD B2B collaboration can be leveraged successfully to implement multi-tenant user management in your case.

•   Azure AD B2B collaboration helps you securely share your company’s applications and services with external guest users as well as internal guest users while also helping you maintain control over access to IT environment and data. Please find the below link for more details on Azure AD B2B collaboration best practices and its implementation: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/multi-tenant-user-management-introduction

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/multi-tenant-user-management-scenarios