# Office 365 Exchange Online - Client credentials - IMAP No Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, office365, imap

I am having an issue with Office 365 Exchange Online IMAP authentication in C#.  I follow multiple guides and videos, but sadly nothing helps.

In Azure I add Office 365 Exchange Online - IMAP.AccessAsApp, POP.AccessAsApp
And granted admin consent.

Email which I am trying to access with IMAP is not in Azure.

I used these commands to add mail permissions.

```
Set-PSRepository
PSGallery

Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Graph

Import-Module AzureAD
Import-module ExchangeOnlineManagement 

Connect-AzureAD -Tenant <Directory (tenant) ID>
$MyApp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString AzureExchange-EmailServiceConnection

Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization <Directory (tenant) ID>
New-ServicePrincipal $MyApp.AppId -ServiceId $MyApp.ObjectId -DisplayName "Service Principal for IMAP APP"

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "test@mail.com" -User $MyApp.ObjectId -AccessRights FullAccess
```

I am trying to connect my Application with MailKit. Also with https://github.com/DanijelkMSFT/ThisandThat/blob/main/Get-IMAPAccessToken.ps1 this test.

In both ways, I am able to obtain AccessToken with IMAP.AccessAsApp role.

I also multiple-check all secrets, ids, and scopes. Wait more than an hour.

IMAP is not authenticated.

```
ERROR during authentication A01 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

I already followed multiple guides and youtube video.

#### 1.Update  07.02.2023

I tried to use different commands from answer.

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString 'testimap'
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString $app.DisplayName
$sp1 = New-ServicePrincipal -AppId $app.AppId -ServiceId $sp.ObjectId -DisplayName "Exchange Service Principal for $($app.DisplayName)"
```

Sadly issue persists.

##### More Info

I am using two accounts one is Azure Admin and I need to specific -Tenant in Connect-AzureAD command.

The second account is an Office Exchange account *NOT IN AZURE* with Admin rights to use New-ServicePrincipal | Add-MailboxPermission

[image: MailboxPermission]

[image: Principal]

[image: CAS]

[image: Azure API Permission]

#### 2.Update  08.02.2023

I am still unable to resolve the issue, so I tried using Graph API to access emails via the client credentials flow.

But I am also having issues there, maybe it is related.

- I am able to obtain access tokens via OAuth2 with all scopes added in Azure portal API permissions.
- I added permission "User.ReadWrite.All" to read information about all users, and it **works**.

Then I add "Mail.ReadWrite" and tried:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/66.......d88d/messages
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-02-08T06:08:44",
            "request-id": "87a638f2-9ff0-4168-aebe-5597c7da3ac8",
            "client-request-id": "87a638f2-9ff0-4168-aebe-5597c7da3ac8"
        }
    }
}
```

I opened Graph Explorer log in with my User account and tried calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
```

And that **works**.

Then I tried:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/6651...d88d/messages
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-02-08T06:27:36",
            "request-id": "70d919c2-52cc-4f14-86f3-77dbad0b48aa",
            "client-request-id": "46e9d490-2b96-5f65-5d5f-5f2e2996f98d"
        }
    }
}
```

Tried the user ID of someone else, the same ID of the user used in me/messages.

The last what I tried was:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/c18c7......43c9137/
```

And that also **works**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution.

The issue was in our Azure setup. We have separate tenants for each product with corresponding email addresses.

Product A - user@a.com

Product B - user@b.com

And then we have Azure account C with all services.

C -> A, B.

I was trying to access email A -> C, and that is not sadly possible.

[Access MS Graph data across tenants and ext principals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70263296/access-ms-graph-data-across-tenants-and-ext-principals)

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/shared-mailbox-access-from-another-o365-tenant/m-p/1350347/highlight/true#M28132

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365/shared-mailbox-between-2-tenants/m-p/97268

The solution was to register the app in the same tenant A -> A.

Thanks, @Rukmini for your help.

Answer (score 2):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the similar error like below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if mailbox access is not granted to the service principal ObjectID.

**To resolve the error, try the below:**

I created the New Service Principal using below commands:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Connect-ExchangeOnline
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -SearchString 'testimap'
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString $app.DisplayName
$sp1 = New-ServicePrincipal -AppId $app.AppId -ServiceId $sp.ObjectId -DisplayName "Exchange Service Principal for $($app.DisplayName)"
```

[image]

Added API permissions to the Application like below:

[image]

And granted the Mailbox permissions to the user like below:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "ruk@xxx.onmicrosoft.com" -User $sp1.ServiceId -AccessRights FullAccess
```

[image]

After doing the above steps, you can execute [Get-IMAPAccessToken.ps1](https://github.com/DanijelkMSFT/ThisandThat/blob/main/Get-IMAPAccessToken.ps1)  and will be authenticated successfully.

If still issue persists, **refer** the below links:

[Exchange Online POP and IMAP OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Flow by Andres Bohren](https://blog.icewolf.ch/archive/2022/12/17/exchange-online-pop-and-imap-oauth-2-0-client-credentials.aspx)

[Exchange Online - Test IMAP OAuth2 Client Credential Flow by Andres Bohren](https://blog.icewolf.ch/archive/2022/12/20/exchange-online-other-ways-of-testing-imap-oauth2-client-credential.aspx)

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried the commands and guides you refer but still nothing. Also in the guides is one time use scope "https://outlook.office.com/.default" and in the second is "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" I think .default is the correct one.

Comment: Yeah .default is the correct one.

Comment: For Office 365 Exchange Online I need to activate Azure Active Directory Premium P2, do I need to assign a user to license? My Office Account is not in Azure do I need to add it as external and then assign a license?

Comment: Yes I guess user must have licence

Comment: I have Azure Active Directory Premium P2. 
I also tried to add an Email address that IMAP I need to the Azure portal and assign a license to it. Still nothing.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but user receive and send emails. Currently, I am using PublicClientApplication to obtain an access token and authenticate to IMAP via MailKit and that works.

Comment: Maybe something helpful, I am currently trying to use Graph alternative, user detail works but messages respond with "Resource could not be discovered.".

Comment: Can you include the query are you trying in Graph?

Comment: I have updated the question with examples of queries I have tried.

Comment: The error is because the user is not the member of the Tenant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251703/discussion-between-psychonek-and-rukmini).